# What is the size of variable after using malloc()?

Tags: c, malloc

I am trying to understand the concept of dynamic memory allocation. I wondered what is the change in size after allocating memory.

My code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char *s;
    printf("Size before malloc: %d\n", sizeof(s));

    s = (char*)malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
    printf("Size after malloc: %d\n", sizeof(s));
    
    printf("Size actual: %d\n", sizeof(s) * 1024);

    s[0] = 'a';
    s[1] = 'b';
    s[2] = 'c';
    s[3] = 'd';
    printf("Size by calculation: %d", sizeof(s) / sizeof(char));

    return 0;
}
```

When I execute this code I get output as follows.

```
Size before malloc: 8
Size after malloc: 8
Size actual: 8192
Size by calculation: 8
```

So why not returns 8192 as size after allocating memory. Further when I added chars into `s` why not getting as `4` ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. `s` is a pointer. Assigning a value to a pointer does not change its type or size. It will always be a pointer and have the size of a pointer. There is no way to get the size of the allocated memory where `s` points to. It is up to you to keep track of the size.

Comment: I see, thanks.  Is there a way to keep track of the size? For instance, may I get the rest of the size later in the code ?

Comment: The `%d` [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format specifier is wrong. The result of the `sizeof` operator is of the data type `size_t`, not `int`. The correct format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`. The format specifier `%d` will probably work on most 32-bit platforms, but I'm not sure if it will work on 64-bit platforms. To be safe on all platforms, you should always use the correct format specifier.

Comment: The phrase _size actual_ would better be stated as _memory allocated_.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thank you for correction. I change it to `%zu` looks like both are printing the same value.

Comment: "Is there a way to keep track of the size?" Use a variable! `size_t size = 1024; char *s = malloc(size); /* ... 42 lines later ... */ printf("allocated %zu bytes for s.\n", size);`

Comment: Your program called `malloc()` with a parameter that is exactly the size to be allocated, so your program knows how to keep track of the size... As for the size of `s`, the type of `s` is `char*` and it is fixed, it is a pointer. You declare a name, and the name is `s`. The name has a type and the type is `char*`. Declare it as `char*           s;` may help you to see it.

Comment: The way to check this is to use a memory debugger. For example you could use Valgrind to keep track of memory allocations. Essentially memory debuggers wrap around `malloc` and `free` calls. As an alternative you could make your own wrapper `my_malloc` and call `malloc` from that, while also logging the size and pointed-to address.

Comment: Thank you guys, your answers helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always find that pictures help in a situation like this.

The declaration

```
char *s;
```

creates a single object of type `char *`:

```
char *
+---+
|   | s
+---+
```

with an *indeterminate* value (not necessarily 0 or any particular value, may be different each time the program is run).

The statement

```
s = (char*)malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
```

allocates space for 1024 `char` objects *somewhere else* in memory, and assigns the address of the first object in that space to `s`:

```
char *        char
+---+         +---+
|   | s ----> |   | s[0]
+---+         +---+
              |   | s[1]
              +---+
              |   | s[2]
              +---+
               ...
```

The size of the `s` variable never changes, only its value.  In this case, its value is the *address* of `s[0]`.

> So why not returns 8192 as size after allocating memory. Further when I added chars into s why not getting as 4 ?

`sizeof(s)` gives you the size of the pointer variable itself, not the size of the object to which it is pointing.  You want to write that call as

```
printf("Size actual: %d\n", sizeof *s * 1024);
```

The *type* of `s` is `char *`, which is going to be greater than 1 on any real world system (4 or 8, depending).  The type of the *expression* `*s` is `char`, which is what you want to use here.

> Further when I added chars into s why not getting as 4 ?

You haven't *added* anything to `s` (or more properly, the buffer it points to) - you've only assigned new values to things that were already there.  You allocated space for 1024 `char` objects, and that size doesn't change just by assigning elements.  Critically, something like

```
s[1026] = some_value;
```

doesn't automatically extend the allocated memory - you're just writing outside of the bounds of that memory.  You have to use the `realloc` library call to increase the size of the allocated block.

Additionally,

```
printf("Size by calculation: %d", sizeof(s) / sizeof(char));
```

doesn't do what you're expecting - Again, `sizeof(s)` gives you the size of the pointer variable itself, not the size of the thing to which it is pointing.  `sizeof(*s)` won't work either, because that gives you the size of a single `char` object, not the entire allocated space.  *You* have to keep track of how much space you allocated in a separate variable:

```
size_t num_elements = 1024;
char *s = malloc( sizeof *s * num_elements );
```

Like I said above, if you need to extend that space later on, you need to use the `realloc` function:

```
/**
 * Double the size of the allocated block.
 */
char *tmp = realloc( s, sizeof *s * (num_elements * 2) ); 
if ( tmp )
{
  s = tmp;
  num_elements *= 2;
}
```

If `realloc` cannot successfully extend the buffer, it will return `NULL` and leave the original buffer in place.  Because of this, we want to assign the result to a temporary variable - we don't want to risk `s` being set to `NULL` and thus losing our only reference to that memory.  Similarly, we don't want to update the size until we know the `realloc` call was successful.

Some style notes -

As of C89, the cast on `malloc` (and `calloc` and `realloc`) is unnecessary and generally considered bad practice.  The more common practice is

```
T *p = malloc( sizeof *p * N ); // for any type T
```

Since the expression `*p` has type `T`, `sizeof *p` is equivalent to `sizeof (T)`.  This way you're not repeating type information multiple times in a single `malloc` call, which eases the maintenance burden (fewer things to update if T ever changes).  This is *not* true in C++ and a cast is still required on `malloc`, `calloc`, and `realloc`, but if you're writing C++ you shouldn't be using C-style memory management in the first place.

Also, remember that `sizeof` is an *operator*, not a function - parentheses are only necessary if the operand is a type name or is an expression containing arithmetic or other operators of lower precedence.  For example,

```
sizeof x+y
```

is parsed as

```
(sizeof x) + y
```

If you want the size of the *expression* `x+y`, then you need to write

```
sizeof (x+y)
```

Comment: That was very comprehensive answer. Thanks a lot, it covered most points for me.

Answer (score 6):

The size of all variables is constant through its entire lifetime. No function call will change the size of a variable.

> So why not returns 8192 as size after allocating memory.

Because the variable is an object of type `char *s` and the size of that type is not 8192 on your system.

Comment: I see, so actually 8192 bytes are allocated in my system but I am printing the size of the char which is not change through code. Thank you.

Comment: @Tolga at least 8192 bytes is allocated if `malloc` returns a non `NULL` result. The runtime may allocate more (but you can't rely on that)

Comment: @Mgetz I see, thank you.

Comment: Because the variable `s` is an object of type `char *`

Comment: @Tolga No, only 1024 bytes were allocated by `malloc(1024 * sizeof(char))`. `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so that is the same as `malloc(1024)`.

Comment: @ryyker I think you meant `malloc(1024 * sizeof(s));`, not `malloc(1024 * sizeof(*s));`.

Comment: @IanAbbott - Oooo,  Your are right!  Thanks.  I will delete that nasty comment now.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof pointer` gives the size of the pointer itself, not the size of the referenced object. So on modern PC machines it will be 4 (32bit system/build)  or 8 (64 bits system/build) bytes.

There is no portable way in C to get the size of the dynamically allocated memory block.

Some remarks.

`sizeof` gives `size_t` type.

```
printf("Size by calculation: %d", sizeof(s) / sizeof(char));
```

invokes undefined behaviour. You need to use the correct format:

```
 printf("Size by calculation: %zu", sizeof(s) / sizeof(char));
```

Comment: @ryyker how does it contradict my answer. You program is 32 bit and it gives 4 bytes.